# Add one more element to array in loop with PHP

Tags: php

I have array like below:

```
$arr=[["id"=>"001","name"=>"Hello","pict"=>"hello.jpg"],["id"=>"002","name"=>"Abc","pict"=>"abc.jpg"]];
```

i want to add one more element to array $arr by "link"=>"uploads/hello.jpg"
My expected result:

```
$arr=[["id"=>"001","name"=>"Hello","pict"=>"hello.jpg","link"=>"uploads/hello.jpg"],["id"=>"002","name"=>"Abc","pict"=>"abc.jpg","link"=>"uploads/abc.jpg"]];
```

Any solution for this thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array using `foreach`, passing a reference into the loop to allow the values to be modified directly:

```
$arr=[["id"=>"001","name"=>"Hello","pict"=>"hello.jpg"],["id"=>"002","name"=>"Abc","pict"=>"abc.jpg"]];

foreach ($arr as &$a) {
    $a['link'] = 'uploads/' . $a['pict'];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 001
            [name] => Hello
            [pict] => hello.jpg
            [link] => uploads/hello.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 002
            [name] => Abc
            [pict] => abc.jpg
            [link] => uploads/abc.jpg
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HD3b9)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each element in the array and set it that way.

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); i++) {
  $arr[$i]['link'] = 'uploads/'.$arr[$i]['pict'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key]['link'] = "uploads/".$value['pict'];
}
```

Use the `foreach` loop to modify the original array. The `$key` value is used to refer to each index in the array.

Comment: thank you very much